# Spring Boot ASync + AutoWired Executor vs manual Executor + Future/Callable?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-boot, spring-async

Is there a drawback to creating and managing your own `ExecutorService` vs using Spring Boot's @Async on a method with an `@Bean` method to create an `Executor`?

To me, doing it manually seems much simpler. I simply create my `ExecutorService` and a method that uses it to schedule a task/`Callable`.

I Spring Boot I would need:

- Decorate the method with `@Async`
- Decorate my Configuration class with `@Configuration`, `@EnableAsync`
- Add an `@Bean` to create an `Executor`

Are there potential issues to doing it manually? Will Spring possibly kill the thread? Are there some other benefits to using the Spring Async pattern?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem most of your hangups are items that are true for a lot of Spring IoC Configuration. The `@Async` is part of the Spring Framework not Spring Boot.

You could handle the executor yourself as you have mentioned but I would question why bother if you have already started to to use the Spring Framework and Spring Boot.

Spring does handle some items itself in the background, such as `shutdown` of the executor when closing the ApplicationContext.

There is also some nice baked in exception handling that can be used along with a complimenting the scheduling aspect of the Spring Framework if you choose to you use it.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-qualification

Having to create `@Bean`, `@Configuration` is a fact of life with Spring and in my opinion not really a draw back, it's just a fact of life with the framework.

Finally, `@Async` abstracts the need to implement `Runnable`, or `@Callable` effectively allow faster implementations of asynchronous capabilities.